# Simplifying polygons to linestring?

Tags: postgis, algorithm, simplify, skeleton

I would like to simplify some polygons that represent rivers into linestrings. I assume that holes in polygons can be omitted. Anybody has some good idea how to simply do it?

It would be nice, if it was possible to be done directly in postgis or by another open source tool, but brief algorithm description will be sufficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you need is called "skeletisation algorithm".

Have a look at this article:

[Haunert, J.-H., Sester, M., Jun. 2008. Area collapse and road centerlines based on straight skeletons. GeoInformatica 12 (2), 169-191.
URL http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10707-007-0028-x](http://www1.pub.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/pub/haunert/pdf/HaunertSester2008.pdf)

Some of these algorithms are developped in the [CGAL library](http://www.cgal.org/).

Comment: Neither link works any more, Julien: do you think you could supply a summary of the algorithms or at least formal references to allow people to look up the papers?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer with a proper reference to a more recent article.

Comment: Thank you!  (Can't add another upvote though--I only had one to give. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In PostGIS 2.2 with SFCGAL, this can be done with [ST_StraightSkeleton](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_StraightSkeleton.html) or [ST_ApproximateMedialAxis](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html), depending on your criteria.

Answer (score 2):

the JUMP skeletonizer plugin is available as part of openjump http://www.openjump.org

Answer (score 1):

Just as a warning, I've never tried this before. Your success will depend on the quality of the data you currently have.

So, think of the polygon as a strip of triangles. Each triangle connects to a vertex on the opposite side of the corridor with an edge. Now, for each of the edges in the corridor, simply place a vertex right smack in the center. These new vertices are the points of your linestring. You can probably fiddle with how you select the middle point on the edge for greater accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, ET GeoWizards might be the answer. Try the [Create Centerlines from Polygons](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/createCenterlines.htm) tool.