# Create centreline from a polygon

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3, algorithm, skeleton

I am working on a project to create a centerline from a polygon automatically. The user select a polygon and click a button, the centerline will create for him.

I have tried the build-in function “Collapse Dual Lines to Centerline”, but it cannot perform well so I decide not use this function in this project. In further study, I find out some terms such as “Medial Axis”, “Skeleton”, “Voronoi polygon”, those are some concepts related to centerline formation. However, I find difficult to understand those algorithm.

Does anyone have a suggestion to me for this project?
Does anyone have a suggestion for how to implement those concepts in ArcMap?
Is there any sample script or algorithm I can refer to as reference?

Development language: C#, VB.Net
ArcGIS : ArcMap 9.3.1

Comment: See also [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177/simplifing-polygons-to-linestring/261#261).

Comment: Are the polygons a fixed width?  Is the width known?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Find Tunnel Center Line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2775/find-tunnel-center-line).