# Creating Centrelines from Road Polygons/Casings using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, road

I want to create center lines from road polygons.

Are there any automated tools in ArcGIS for Desktop to do this?

I am including a Screenshot of my vector file below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The solution to convert to image then vectorize did have some snapping issues, but produced much better results than collapse dual lines (totally unaccepatable). Now to automate tackling the snapping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally i got a solution. I converted the polygon to image in arcgis using Polygon to raster tool. Then reclassified it and used Automatic vectorization. About 90 percent accuracy is obtained using this method. There are only little snapping mismatches and also the line is drawn through the exact centre. I think this is the best way if you do not have a ET geowizards licence.

The [ArcScan for ArcGIS home page](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/arcscan) says:

> Starting with the release of ArcGIS 10.1, ArcScan for ArcGIS is
>   included in all license levels of ArcGIS Desktop software at no
>   additional cost.

Comment: @fatih_dur "Starting with the release of ArcGIS 10.1, ArcScan for ArcGIS is included in all license levels of ArcGIS Desktop software at no additional cost." http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/arcscan

Comment: @PolyGeo, I have removed my comment after your edit to the answer, still meself do not think the accepted solution is robust enough.

Comment: @fatih_dur when I think an answer is not useful, I downvote it (as per its tooltip).

Comment: That's what i did way back. thanks for the licence level info regarding ArcScan, could be handy.

Answer (score 16):

**Collapse Dual Lines To Centerline (Cartography)**

This is a specific ArcGIS tool requiring ArcInfo License

```
ArcGIS for Desktop Basic: No
ArcGIS for Desktop Standard: No
ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced: Yes
```

Convert you polygons to lines first

*"Derives centerlines from dual-line (or double-line) features, such as road casings, based on specified width tolerances."*

[image]

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00700000000t000000

Comment: Thanks for the information, I already tried center line from dual line feature in arcgis. But it didnt work correctly. Using Collapse dual line to single line dosent create line in the centre. Can u suggest any other method

Comment: Finally i got a solution. I converted the polygon to image in arcgis using Polygo to raster tool. Then reclassified it and used Automatic vectorization. about 90 percent accuracy is obtained using this method.

Comment: I know this hasn't been commented in a while, but when I run polygon to raster it is throwing an error (99999), does not even start processing

Answer (score 13):

you can check out ET GeoTools for ArcGIS [here](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/createCenterlines.htm). Beside this you can check out Feature To Line (Data Management) [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000039000000) but you have to some engaging in.

and check out [Finding tunnel 'center line'?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2775) skeletisation algorithms may can help you to develop your tool.

Input Dataset

[image: et]

Result

[image: et1]
[image: et2]

Comment: Thanks, this information helps me a lot. One more doubt, s it possible to convert the polygon to a raster image and then auto vectorize the image through center. Is this method a better one than the previous one, please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[image]

These two modeling available in ESRI software. After you can run 1st modeling we will do trim on lines model 2.

Comment: This is a great framework but trimming the line >10 times isn't optimal of which I have found on a test data set.

Answer (score 3):

There is no single geoprocessing tool that automatically performs this task. The tools used in this procedure require an ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced license-

1.Convert the polygon layer to a line feature class by using the Polygon to Line tool.

2.Remove the lines enclosing the polyline layer.

3.Save the edits, and stop the edit session.

4.Create the centerlines by using the Collapse Dual Lines To Centerline tool. The tool is located in the Cartography toolbox > Generalization toolset. The centerlines are displayed in the map.

http://support.esri.com/cN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/44238

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Pro now has a [Polygon to Centerline tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/topographic-production/polygon-to-centerline.htm), available if you have the Production Mapping extension with a standard or advanced license.