# How to extract breaklines from a given DEM?

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, dem, breaklines

Breaklines are very useful for describing a terrain - for example to build an exact TIN.

My question is, how to extract these breaklines from a given DEM?

I calculated the curvature (vertical) - raster (using arcgis 10), where you can see the breaklines (min/max-curvature), but I did not figure out how to extract them to get polylines in the end.

What is the workflow to get these breaklines from a DEM?

Does anyone have an idea of a workflow, or a "tool", or skript, which can help?

I think I am not the first/last man who wants to perform this task:)

...in the meanwhile i have found **[a paper on this topic](http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/xxxiii/congress/part3/109_XXXIII-part3.pdf)** that seems to be a good solution, but the big question remains: how to reduce that to practice?

Or has anyone a different (easier?) approach with some software?

Comment: As far as I can remember, **[QuikGrid](http://www.galiander.ca/quikgrid/)** can detect breaklines very well, although it mostly works with mass points.

Comment: What kind of breaklines are you interested in extracting? The most common would be hydro-flattening but breaklines can be used for roads.I don't understand the question as the breaklines are needed prior to creating the DEM. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

I would try it this way:
search for a critical value in the curvature raster file. Above this value you will expect a breakline.

Then I would use conditional statements in the raster calculator to use "1" for pixels above the critical and 0 below the critical value.
Use this binary raster for raster to polygon conversion in the toolbox.
you will find an answer on how to get the polygon to line [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29863/create-centrelines-from-road-polygons)

after all you can build up a model from these steps.

Comment: might have to use nibble or some thinning function based on what comes out, but I think @butcher's answer is on the mark.

Answer (score 2):

[Conrec](http://paulbourke.net/papers/conrec/) does this. It was originally written in fortran though, so it has been ported around a few times.

A library I have been working on in node.js, [turf](https://github.com/morganherlocker/turf), uses this algorithm to create these contours based of point vector data. The script to do this is pretty simple and would basically be:

```
var t = require('turf')
var fs = require('fs')
var z = 'elevation'
var resolution = 15
var breaks = [.1, 22, 45, 55, 65, 85,  95, 105, 120, 180]

t.load('./path/to/points.geojson', function(err, points){
  t.contour(points, z, resolution, breaks, function(err, contours){
    if(err) throw err
    fs.writeFileSync('.path/to/output.geojson', contours)
  })
})
```

You can also generate jenks natural breaks if you do not have specific breaks in mind:

```
var t = require('turf')
var propertyName = 'elevation'
var num = 10

t.load('./path/to/points.geojson', function(err, pts){
  if(err) throw err
  t.jenks(pts, 'elevation', num, function(err, breaks){
    if(err) throw err
    console.log(breaks) // [ 11, 12, 18, 25, 29, 41, 50, 55, 76, 90, 143 ]
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go to my VA lidar [site](http://www.wm.edu/as/cga/VALIDAR/index.php) and look for a project with Breaklines. We have many.

For example 2010 / 2011 Eleven County Coastal VA Lidar. You'll see links to all the reports and other documents and this explains how they made the breaklines usually in ArcGIS. Try a few differing projects for differing methods but I can tell you the NHD is often used, as are ridges as derived from a DEM. Mostly the reports are in the metadata.  Here is the [one](http://gisfiles.wm.edu/files/lidar/a11county/METADATA/PROJECT_REPORT/Final%20Project%20Report%20for%20USGS%20Virginia%20LiDAR_01312011.pdf) for above. CTRL F Breaklines in the pdf.