# Extracting centerline of a Complex-Polygon in PostGIS/Python

Tags: python, postgis, voronoi-thiessen

Any idea how to extract the centerline of the following polygon (Fig1) using PostGIS functions or Python modules? I was trying [Voronoi Function](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ninv6umibuk0e1e/voronoi.sql) but thats not helpful for this kind of shape. I want something like Fig2 blackline.

[image: Fig1: Polygon Shape]
[image: Fig2: Centerline]

Comment: You may want to look at this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29863/creating-centrelines-from-road-polygons-casings   I know it uses ArcGIS instead, but the approach may be useful.

Comment: How about: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_StraightSkeleton.html ?

Comment: @Jakub I am trying to configure SFCGAL (necessary for Skeleton function) to my already existing PostGIS db. Although I have installed the `libSFCGAL.so` file in `/usr/local/lib` directory but don't know how to bring `ST_StriaghtSkeleton()` in the db? Any idea?

Comment: PostGIS needs to be compiled with SFCGAL support, but that's a diffrent question and not something I'm too familiar with.

Comment: @Jakub Thanks. I have somehow solved this SFCGAL configuration by myself [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114790/configuring-sfcgal-to-postgis-db/114944#114944)

Answer (score 4):

This may be a wrong tool for you, but you can do it simply with OpenJUMP and Skeletonizer plugin. Plugin can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jump-pilot/files/OpenJUMP_plugins/More%20Plugins/JUMP%20Skeletonizer%20Plugin/

Zip file contains a good manual. Plugin is meant for streams and water bodies but your polygon mimics a stream to me.

This is your polygon as I digitized it. Notice vertices in the center lines of inputs/outlets.

[image]

Entry points digitized on a separate layer. Points must snap to vertices on the polygon boundary.

[image]

Use the Skeletonizer tools and fill in the fields

[image]

Get the result

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the jar file contains no manual. Could you please guide me how to add this plugin to my OpenJump-GUI?

Comment: Look inside the **zip**, in skeletonizer-1.0\doc\ you should find file "SkeletonizerUserGuide.doc". Installation is done by dropping the jar files from skeletonizer-1.0\lib\ into lib\ext directory in OpenJUMP.

Comment: However, it looks like most jars or newer versions of those are already included in OpenJUMP either in \lib or in \lib\ext. Perhaps it is best to copy just those which seem to be missing. Restart is needed after adding new jars.

Comment: I found this jar [here](http://geo.michaelm.free.fr/OpenJUMP/resources/skeletonizer-1.0.zip).
But I am getting this error `java.lang.Exception: Could not determine shapefile type - data is either all GeometryCollections or empty (Illegal State Exception)` while running this Skeletonizer plugin

Answer (score 4):

If your polygon is raster, digitize it.

Once your polygon is really a polygon :), a first solution lies, like @WhiteboxDev said, it's the straight skeleton, but it has the problem that, besides the centerline you want, it also returns a lot of segments radiating from that line to the border of your polygon. But if you have PostGIS 2.2+, you can use [`ST_ApproximateMedialAxis()`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html) instead, which is what you want.