# Input a geometry spline through a negative buffer

Tags: geometry, buffer, shapely, spline

**Update** My question is a duplicate of [Extracting centerline of a Complex-Polygon in PostGIS/Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114541/extracting-centerline-of-a-complex-polygon-in-postgis-python/203928) (though if anyone has a programmatic solution - that is, not ArcGIS but rather Py, C, Java, etc. - I would be interested).

Let's say I have shape such as the below:
[image]

From this shape, I want to perform a negative buffer that produces the following:
[image]

The rough idea was to perform a negative buffer that exceeded the diameter of the geometry at any given point. This does not work, though, and leads to an empty geometry.

How might I perform a geometric operation on a shape so as to impute its centermost points? Is some form of negative buffering a reasonable approach? Or, is there a more well-word path to achieving the spline of such geometries?

Comment: check this function out https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html you will have to enable or create the SFCGAL extension to use it

Comment: Awesome - thanks much!

Any chance someone's already done the heavy lifting on implementing this in vanilla Python (aware it will be slower). Either way, this is the solution!

Comment: i think the function comes from this library http://sfcgal.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @ziggy:

> check this function out
>   https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html you will have
>   to enable or create the SFCGAL extension to use it

and

> i think the function comes from this library http://sfcgal.org/