# How to extract road centreline from delaunay triangulation using open source QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins

From some months I have been solving a problem but I cannot finish. My question is, "How can I extract a road centreline from delaunay triangulation using open-source QGIS?" Actually, I am using Chugiak.

Comment: Can you give some more detail about the relationship between your Delaunay triangulation, and the road centerlines?

Comment: are you referring to the problem described in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29863/creating-centrelines-from-road-polygons-casings?