# The average distance between the roads

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, connection, connectivity-analysis, lines-to-points

I have two vector layers.

1. Roads Line  layer
2. Roads Point layer

I want somehow to get the average value of the distance between each  roads and get average value for my region. Each road has its own ID. Is it possible to get it automatically, vector or raster results?
I use QGIS and ArcGIS, any solution will be OK.
[image]
This is manually connected.
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the desired end result? Why does the solution by @mixedbredie not meet your needs for "calculat[ing] the density of the road network?"

Comment: "I want somehow to get the average value of the distance between the roads. In fact I need to calculate the density of the road network" - that sounds like two separate **and totally different** questions. Clarify?

Comment: For one region I want to show how much the average distance for all roads with one value in meters. After that, I propose where the network of roads is to be thicker and reduce the average distance. For city roads this is not relevant but for roads outside the city, this information may be important

Comment: Please decide which GIS software you wish to ask about in this particular question. Asking about multiple makes it too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the road density per unit area you could overlay a grid and then sum length per cell.

In QGIS there is an analysis tool called **Sum Line Length** which does exactly this. This would ignore the point layer though.

[image: line length tool]

The grid can then be styled using either the count or summed length fields as a measure of the density.

[image: summed line length]

[image: number of lines per cell]

Comment: I need the distance between the roads and not the road density on the surface. See figure 2.

Comment: How do you assign pairs of points? Could you just use the points layer and do a nearest neighbour analysis grouping by cell - where mean distance is lower roads are closer together?

Comment: Link points, it can also, but how

Comment: not easily - this might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160574/calculating-avg-distance-between-two-non-parallet-lines

Comment: Maybe a model with some iterative form of Near Analysis, where each point in the road finds the nearest point of the adjacent road? The difficult part would be the selection process to ensure that you are selecting the adjacent road...

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using raster analysis for this problem.  Converting the road network to a raster and performing proximity analysis (using Arc or QGIS) should result in a raster of continuous values representing distance from the nearest road: [image: Proximity]Next, we create a polygon shapefile of the area contained within the streets. And lastly, utilizing Zonal Statistics in QGIS, add fields to the polygons shapefile with the Mean/Min/Max values from your Proximity Raster:[image: Classified density by block]

Comment: "For one region I want to show how much the average distance for all roads with one value in meters. After that, I propose where the network of roads is to be thicker and reduce the average distance. For city roads this is not relevant but for roads outside the city, this information may be important "

In this case then - you might want to extract the ridge line from a proximity raster - that would be the line equidistant from two roads.   SAGA (within the Processing Toolbox of QGIS) has a "Valley and Ridge Detection" tool which would pull these out for you.

Comment: I do not have this SAGA tool. I use QGIS 2.18. And SAGA 2.3.2 (249 geoalgorithms)

Comment: At least QGIS 2.18.12 (Win10 64-bit) got 364 geoalgorithms in the SAGA-toolbox. Geostatistics > Zonal raster statistics