# Create polygon center line with Python script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon

Does anyone have a stand alone python script that will find the center line of a polygon and output as a separate feature class? I have a basic ArcMap license 10.6 (no extensions) and I would like to develop a modelbuilder tool to iterate several polygons, find their center lines and store the center lines as a separate feature class in another folder or GDB.

Comment: I've done this in C# ArcObjects and cringe at the thought of implementing a bisected TIN and Djikstras' algorithm in python. Do you have any code? How proficient are you at python? Have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29863/creating-centrelines-from-road-polygons-casings-using-arcgis-desktop/43952#43952 and its parent https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis for some ideas, as for how you implement this in python with a basic license... IDK. It might be quicker to draw them!

Comment: If you've no extensions and a basic licence may be worth looking at qgis as a solution?

Comment: I've used Qgis in the past, however, I need to stick with ArcMap and use its modelbuilder tools - work requirement.