# Finding centrelines from polygons in R sf

Tags: r, polygon, sf

Has anyone found a solution for turning polygons into centrelines using R? It has to be in R as I'm deploying it in parallel on a UNIX cluster. I've got as far as:

```
library(sf)    
centreline <- st_cast(polygon$geometry, "LINESTRING")
```

But this outputs the entire polygon boundary rather than the centreline.

Here are two solutions in ArcGIS and QGIS.

[Creating Centrelines from Road Polygons/Casings using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29863/creating-centrelines-from-road-polygons-casings-using-arcgis-desktop/43952#43952)

[Finding centrelines from polygons in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis)

Sample data and code of what I've already tried:

[Data](https://swanseauniversity-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/j_a_h_jones_swansea_ac_uk/Ed_bPRTnvnpNhqZ_Ne0AU90BP9IzkkUzmQN0b-_fdvYv_Q?e=kZK6ga)

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# inputs
linepath <- 'river.shp'
pointpath <- 'river_point.shp'
epsg <- 27700 

line <- st_read(dsn = linepath) %>% st_transform(epsg)

point <- st_read(dsn = pointpath) %>% st_transform(epsg)

# Buffer point 
bufferpoint <- st_buffer(point, dist = 1)  %>%
  st_transform(epsg) 

# Cut line with point
# A helper function that erases all of y from x:
st_erase = function(x, y) st_difference(x, st_union(st_combine(y))) 

splitline <- st_erase(line, bufferpoint) %>% 
  mutate(id = as.factor(row_number()))

buffered <- st_buffer(splitline, dist = 0.5) 

dissolved <- st_union(buffered) %>% as('Spatial') %>% st_as_sf()

singlepart <- st_cast(dissolved, 'POLYGON') %>%
  mutate(id = as.factor(row_number()))

centreline <- st_cast(singlepart$geometry, "LINESTRING")
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question I answered on Stack OVerflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595117/identify-a-linear-feature-on-a-raster-map-and-return-a-linear-shape-object-using/9643004#9643004 - that was designed with `sp` spatial classes but its trivial to convert to that.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately my data relates to river polygons and your method (which is great) doesn't work at intersections.

Comment: A picture of your data (or a sample of it) would be very useful.

Comment: Please don't use `library(tidyverse)`, try and only include packages that you use rather than pulling in an entire universe. At first glance it looks like `dplyr` is the only thing needed.

Comment: Take a look at the `cmgo` package. It has `CM.calculateCenterline` function. https://github.com/AntoniusGolly/cmgo