# Creating "average" line from multiple adjacent polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, line, polyline-creation

I have a set of stream channels that are currently being represented by multiple adjacent polygons rather than by actual lines. See the green polygons in the image below. The polygons are essentially a pixelated version of the stream channels.

So I'm looking for a way to basically create a line to replace the polygons. The way I picture it, the lines would go through the vertex of two polygons that are kitty-corner from one another. In theory (I think)  any straight section of channel is just represented by a single elongated pixel, so as long as the lines are taking a sort of diagonal slope through each single pixel and crossing through the vertices, it should end up following the "true" stream channel.

I've tried converting features to lines and it just ends up giving me all the borders of each pixel, rather than a single line going through them.

[image]

Comment: Check this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/29863/29431

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should be able to do this by buffering your existing polygons using a distance perhaps 10% of the width of your smallest polygons, and using the option to have the inner borders of your buffers dissolved.

This should give you a single polygon feature suitable for [Creating Centrelines from Road Polygons/Casings using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29863/creating-centrelines-from-road-polygons-casings-using-arcgis-desktop)