# Is it possible to "re-buffer" river polygon dataset?

Tags: qgis, buffer, line, data-management

I've river polygon data representing the water quality. This polygon data were derived from polyline dataset according to a buffer distance in the attribute table. Unfortunately I don't have this line dataset. So my "possibly naive" question is - is it possible to "re-buffer" the polygon data set to have polyline data again? Maybe there is a way to draw the centerline of each polygon?
I prefer to work with qgis 2.6 but also have ArcGIS 2.2 available.

Comment: sorry, but this functionality supplies the outline of the whole polygon. I need the center line.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, in that case take a look at this:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons The ET geowizards Create centerlines works well, but you may be limited to the number of features you can work with in the free version.

Comment: Look at this also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177/simplifying-polygons-to-linestring/215#215

Comment: Manual of OpenJUMP skeletonizer is good reading even if you will use other tools. It is included in the zip http://sourceforge.net/projects/jump-pilot/files/OpenJUMP_plugins/More%20Plugins/JUMP%20Skeletonizer%20Plugin/