# Buffering polygon until it hits neighbor using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, buffer

I have a shapefile made up of a number of polygons. 
Neighboring polygons often share an attribute.

What I need to do is buffer these polygons based on the common attribute. However, I would like to expand said buffers until they meet, at which point they can stop.

I have a hastily put together mock-up:

[image: poorlyDrawExample]

All I have code-wise is the following:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.analysis import *

layer=qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer() 

QgsGeometryAnalyzer().dissolve(layer, "D:/test_dissolved.shp", onlySelectedFeatures=False, uniqueIdField=3, p=None)
```

Truthfully I am not very well versed in the QGIS API documentation and despite my best efforts I cannot find a suitable method for this. 
`QgsGeometryAnalyzer().dissolve` allows me to dissolve the buffer but that isn't what I am after.

Should I perhaps be looking in another direction here?

Answer (score 5):

Something you could try is a thiessen process where you voronoi the polygons then dissolve by similar attributes.  I don't know what this would be in python but maybe the steps are useful to you.

Comment: I am going to have a go at figuring out the Voronoi route using pyQGIS and see where it takes me. I prefer the idea of using an open source solution.

Comment: What do you mean by open source? QGIS and all its tools come under the free open source licence.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to explore raster analysis functions. See [Creating centreline for every polygon in submarine canyon database using ArcGIS for Desktop Basic?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153829/creating-centreline-for-every-polygon-in-submarine-canyon-database-using-arcgis) and [Creating Thiessen (Voronoi) polygons using lines (rather than points) as the input features?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53414/creating-thiessen-voronoi-polygons-using-lines-rather-than-points-as-the-inp) for further inspiration.

This requires you to use a suitable raster resolution of course.

Comment: I like this idea of converting to a raster and it had occurred to me but would a large dataset not result in a very slow processing time?

Comment: Maybe not slower than doing the same iteratively with vectors.

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly related task the other day. In theorie, voronoi polygons with (weighted) building centrepoints should just be the solution for your case but it didn't work for me;
PostgreSQL is not what you asked for, but, as a workaround, if it's the 'centreline' between each building you're after for the first step, using PostGIS [ST_ApproximateMedialAxis](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html) could be worth a try. You'd have to create a base polygon for the whole study area and cut out the building polygons prior to apply the function on the base polygon to get related results. Could work, might not...