# "Average" of two lines

Tags: line, simplify, generalization, computational-geometry

I have a dataset of pairs of parallel linear features (railway tracks) and I  need to simplify each pair into its central/median line. This could be achieved by computing a skeleton as suggested in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177/simplifying-polygons-to-linestring) but I am looking for a simpler solution: a line being the "average" of the two input lines would be a fair approximation. For example:

[image]

Would such transformation be implemented in any mainstream GIS software or library?

Comment: обратите внимание на эти два решения, я думаю они вам должны помочь: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/295348/120129; https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318733/120129

Answer (score 1):

There is an ArcGIS tool called Collapse Dual Lines to Center line that will accomplish this task.   The tool requires and Advanced ArcGIS license.  [Here is a link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/collapse-dual-lines-to-centerline.htm) to the tools help for 10.x

GRASS also has a tool called v.Centerline that will work in both GRASS or via the GRASS tools in QGIS.  [Here is a link](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/addons/v.centerline.html) to the GRASS tool.